# Identificar elemento em uma imagem com PHP?

Tags: php

Existe alguma ferramenta ou forma para verificar se existe um elemento dentro de uma imagem em PHP? O sistema precisa identificar que o elemento da primeira imagem também está na segunda imagem.

Exemplo:

[image: Exemplo]

Answer (score 5):

Existe uma biblioteca javascript de face detection, adaptando ela creio que sirva a sua necessidade:

http://facedetection.jaysalvat.com/